# How can I manipulate the CDF of a sample such that it matches that of a different sample?

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy, weather

I want to use CDF matching to correct raw model forecasts of precipitation (but the application is fairly generic).

Assuming CDF B below is the observed CDF (the CDF that I trust), I want to calculate the difference between CDF A and B so that on a given day I can take the precipitation forecast and shift it by the difference between A and B so that it is more representative of B instead of A.

So for each x-value, I need to get the y-value of A, then where B is that same value I need to get the x-value, giving me 2 x-values from which to calculate a difference.

Of course, this only gives me discrete x-values where I know the correction, so I guess I'll need to do additional work to correct an x-value that falls between 2 others.

Here is the Python code I used to generate the samples:

```py
import numpy.random
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

quantiles = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 10, 15, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 75, 100]

# Generate fake precip data
sample_size = 100000
A = numpy.random.gamma(0.7, scale=50, size=sample_size)
B = numpy.random.gamma(0.5, scale=70, size=sample_size)
ens = (40 - 20) * np.random.random_sample((21)) + 20

# Calculate histograms
A_pdf, edges = np.histogram(A, bins=quantiles)
A_pdf = A_pdf / sample_size
A_cdf = np.cumsum(A_pdf)
B_pdf, edges = np.histogram(B, bins=quantiles)
B_pdf = B_pdf / sample_size
B_cdf = np.cumsum(B_pdf)

# Plot CDFs
plt.figure()
plt.plot(quantiles[1:], A_cdf, 'x-', c='r', lw=3, ms=10, mew=2, label='A')
plt.plot(quantiles[1:], B_cdf, '+-', c='k', lw=3, ms=15, mew=2, label='B')
plt.xticks(quantiles[1:])
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
```

[image]

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is a function that approximates the CDF of A, and one that approximates the inverse CDF (or PPF) of B. You would then simply compute *q<sub>corrected</sub> = PPF<sub>B</sub>(CDF<sub>A</sub>(q))*.

For your example data we can simply use the `.cdf` and `.ppf` methods for `scipy.stats.gamma` [frozen distributions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.rv_continuous.html#scipy.stats.rv_continuous) with the appropriate parameters:

```
from scipy import stats

distA = stats.gamma(0.7, scale=50)
distB = stats.gamma(0.5, scale=70)

corrected_quantiles = distB.ppf(distA.cdf(quantiles[1:]))
```

Of course, for real data you are unlikely to know the parameters of the true underlying distributions. If you have a good idea of their functional form, you could try performing a maximum likelihood fit to your data in order to estimate them:

```
distA = stats.gamma(*stats.gamma.fit(A))
distB = stats.gamma(*stats.gamma.fit(B))
```

Failing that, you could try to interpolate/extrapolate from your empirical CDFs, for example using [`scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.InterpolatedUnivariateSpline.html):

```
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline

# cubic spline interpolation
itp_A_cdf = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(quantiles[1:], A_cdf, k=3)
# the PPF is the inverse of the CDF, so we simply reverse the order of the
# x & y arguments to InterpolatedUnivariateSpline
itp_B_ppf = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(B_cdf, quantiles[1:], k=3)

itp_corrected_quantiles = itp_B_ppf(itp_A_cdf(quantiles[1:]))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.hold(True)
ax.plot(quantiles[1:], A_cdf, '-r', lw=3, label='A')
ax.plot(quantiles[1:], B_cdf, '-k', lw=3, label='B')
ax.plot(corrected_quantiles, A_cdf, '--xr', lw=3, ms=10, mew=2, label='exact')
ax.plot(itp_corrected_quantiles, A_cdf, '--+b', lw=3, ms=10, mew=2,
        label='interpolated')
ax.legend(loc=5)
```

[image]

Comment: Worked wonderfully, thanks again. I've created an [iPython notebook](https://gist.github.com/mike-charles/0ea03b5634da95a3d296) to document the methodology.

Comment: [Here's](https://gist.github.com/mikecharles/0ea03b5634da95a3d296) the correct link to the iPython notebook